# Is there a way to throttle S3 backups when using this code?

Tags: amazon-s3, backup

I'm using the S3 backup code at https://github.com/woxxy/MySQL-backup-to-Amazon-S3

eg

```
# daily MySQL backup to S3 (not on first day of month or sundays)
0 3 2-31 * 1-6 sh /home/youruser/mysqltos3.sh day
```

Is there a way to throttle the upload, so it doesn't eat all my bandwidth during the upload? People are being booted from my server during the 15mins it takes to process, and my CPU is running at, according to the stats charts, 200%.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Googling `throttle bandwidth for program linux` seems to yield a lot of results, worth checking out. E.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-a-process

Comment: CPU != bandwidth.  If you're maxing one, it's unlikely that you're maxing the other.